# Rest Assured, Java - using TLS/SSL certificate in post request

Tags: java, ssl, postman, rest-assured

I red probably all answers regarding using the TLS certificate in Rest Assured, unfortunately with all of them I get an error message:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

But let's start from the beginning:
I got from the service which I try to reach file .crt(certificate file is 2 way certificate - [two way certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GJPR.png)) and RSA private key (.key). Once I merged them to the one PKCS12 file with  openssl:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey MY_KEY.key -in MY_FILE.crt
```

and imported to the POSTMAN with configuration [postman setting-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRgnf.png), [postman setting-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVKCA.png). I get correct response.

Once I try to use it in the Java code:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig()
.keyStore("src/test/resources/testdata/sslCerts/keystore.p12", "PASSWORD"));
```

or

```
.given()
        .spec(new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setAuth(RestAssured
                .certificate("src/test/resources/testdata/sslCerts/keystore.p12","PASSWORD",
                    CertificateAuthSettings
                        .certAuthSettings()
                        .keyStoreType("pkcs12")
                        )).build())
```

I get the error from above.
When I try to use for example relaxed HTTPs/allow all host names or disable SSL verification I get response:

```
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig()
        .allowAllHostnames()
        .relaxedHTTPSValidation());
```

I get the response from the server:

> 496 - Client TLS certificate missing - please provide a valid
> TLS client certificate to access this service

Do you have any info how can I use provided certificate as a server and client site validation certificate and get correct response from server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be caused by that you're configuring only a keystore, but not a truststore.

Key stores are typically used for keeping the keys or certs to provide to a third party. But for validating the provided certificates trust stores are used.

Try to do something like:

```java
RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig()
.keyStore("src/test/resources/testdata/sslCerts/keystore.p12", "PASSWORD")
.trustStore("src/test/resources/testdata/sslCerts/keystore.p12", "PASSWORD"));
```

Your trust store has to contain the certificate that is returned by your service or the certificate chain that was used to sign service certificate.

Comment: The certificate which I got in enhanced key usage have both ways (client and server authentication) defined. Doesn't it mean that I can use it as a keystone cert together with provided RSA private key and also import it to existing cacerts or create new truststore just with this certificate imported? 
Do I need completely separate certificate? Because when I tried with:
.trustStore("src/test/resources/testdata/sslCerts/keystore.p12", "PASSWORD")
I have the same issue.

Comment: You need to check the sertificate that remote service provides. The fact the sertificate you have is "two-way" only means that you can use it in two ways. That does not mean the remote service uses it to prove its identity.